# Flexpaper apis won't work in any way

Tags: javascript, html, flash, apache-flex, flexpaper

Everything works in flexpaper but it's api ...

I' using the free version of flexpaper but when I use their API like:

```
function onDocumentLoaded(totalPages){
    getDocViewer().searchText('UK');
}
```

as shown in Flexpaper examples, but nothing seems to work...

Anyone already had this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what version of FlexPaper you are using, but I noticed that somewhere between 1.4.2 and 1.5.1 the getDocViewer function was silently removed from the support javascript code. There is no mention of this removal in the change log.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(function() {
    $('#documentViewer').bind('onDocumentLoaded',function(){
        window.$FlexPaper = window.getDocViewer = window["$FlexPaper"] = function(id){
            var instance = (id==="undefined")?"":id;

            if (window['ViewerMode'] == 'flash') {
                return window["FlexPaperViewer_Instance"+instance].getApi();
            }else if(window['ViewerMode'] == 'html'){
                return window["FlexPaperViewer_Instance"+instance];
            }
        };
        $FlexPaper('documentViewer').searchText('UK');
    });
});
</script>
```

Where $FlexPaper is your FlexPaper instance's ID